# Multiple tracking of NFT markers ARToolkit android

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm trying to track multiple NFT markers simultaneously, but with no success.

In the [changelog](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) it is possible to see that they added this feature in the ARWrapper some months ago. Unfortunately it is quite complex, and i couldn't find any example for android.

I would like to know if there are some examples or tutorials on how to do this.

**NB:** I'm talking about **NFT markers**, that are different from hiro, kanji etc.

Comment: It's strange, because with more than one marker, it seems that everything is ok, but actually only the first marker is recognized.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue introduced on version 5.3 where the tracker was replaced.

You can wait for it to be fixed in a newer release or move to version 5.2, which uses a different tracker that does not have this bug.

Comment: shalafi is absolutely correct. Multi-page NFT is currently nonfunctional, and would require a regression to 5.2.x. Keep in mind that if you use the 5.2.x version of ARToolKit, there are licensing issues around libKPM. http://artoolkit.org/artoolkit-licensing